# Using a PHP POST form inside javascript - jquery .load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I'm using a fairly standard HTML/PHP form to update tables in a MYSQL database. When I load the form into a web browser directly it works just fine. When I try loading the form through javascript (via a larger website) the forms displays but doesn't do anything. When i click the submit button nothing happens - and no errors are generated anywhere I can see. Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
this.display_admin_table_header = function () {

    current_pane.send_get_admin_table_data = this.send_get_admin_table_data;
    $('#admin_tab').addClass('selected');
    $('#stat_table').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
    $('#stat_table').load('form2.php');  //<--form i'm loading
}
```

Here is the web form:

```
<html>
<head>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'my_db';
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$node = $_POST['label'];
$mode  = $_POST['mode'];
$department = $_POST['department'];
$ip = $_POST['ip'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$db = $_POST['db'];


$sql = "INSERT into device ".
   "SET label = '$node' , ".
  # "SET mode = $mode ".
  # "SET department = $department ".
  # "SET ip = $ip ".
  # "SET username = $username ".
  # "SET password = $password ".
   "db = $db ";

error_log(" $sql \n");
if(! mysqli_query( $conn,$sql ))
{
 die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{ 
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
     <td width="100">Node </td>
  <td><input name="label" type="text" id="label"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td width="100">Site-Bucket </td>
     <td><input name="department" type="text" id="department"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td width="100">Mode </td>
      <td><input name="mode" type="radio" id="mode" value="1">Cmode <br>
     <input name="mode" type="radio" id="mode" value="2">7mode<br> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td width="100">Node Man. IP </td>
     <td><input name="ip" type="text" id="ip"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="100">Username </td>
    <td><input name="username" type="text" id="username"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="100">Password </td>
    <td><input name="password" type="text" id="password"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td width="100">DB in use?</td>
      <td><input name="db" type="radio" id="db" value=1>Yes <br>
      <input name="db" type="radio" id="db" value=0>No <br> </td>
</tr>
       <td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
       <td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
}  
?>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Well there is more to a form that the html (which is all you are getting with js load(); )

Comment: What does the source of the generated page look like? Is the form present inside `<form>` tags? Is there another JS function that is doing the submit and the button assigned to it?

Comment: Why is your if statement wrapped in `{}`? where is `status` defined? where is `msg` and `xhr` defined? copy paste error?

Comment: I've added the entire PHP form.

Comment: Where are the opening `<html>` and `<body>` tags?

Comment: they were in there, just got cut off in the 'code' formatting. Either way, the page works perfectly when loaded outside javascript!

Comment: Make the action an absolute path

Comment: Paste the source for the loaded page

Comment: The source from the loaded page just shows the JS associated with the main site - nothing related to embedded page (even though all the HTML shows up just fine).

Comment: @user574632 - can you give me an example of what you mean by making it an absolute path?

Comment: action="http://www.mysite.com/form.php" - the problem is that the loaded html form posts to the page it is loaded into which does not have any form handleing php code. You need it to post to the original url

Comment: using an absolute path in the action makes no difference.